# Как отсортировать с помощью filter() свойство компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import ItemsList from "../src/components/App"



const propsValues = {
  title: "Список смартфонов",
  items: [
          "HTC U Ultra", 
          "iPhone 7", 
          "Google Pixel", 
          "Hawei P9", 
          "Meizu Pro 6",
          "iPhone 7",  
          "Asus Zenfone 3"
  ]
};


render(<ItemsList data={propsValues} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

сам файл компонентов

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <li>{this.props.name}</li>;
  }
}

class ItemsList extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return(
          <div>         
              <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
              <ul>
              {
                  this.props.data.items.map(function(item){                       
                      return <Item key={item} name={item} />
                  })
              }
              </ul>
          </div>);
  }
}


 export default ItemsList;
```

Как с помощью filter отсортировать в компоненте списка нужное?
инструкция типа

```
this.props.data.items.filter(function(item){                       
                      return <Item key={item} name={item === "iPhone 7"} />
                  })
```

не работает

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать следующим образом:

```
render(){
    let goodItems = this.props.data.items.filter(item => item === "iPhone 7");
    return(
      <div>         
          <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
          <ul>
          {
              goodItems.map(item => <Item key={item} name={item} />)
          }
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: значение "key" также рекомендуется давать элементам уникальное (но не индекс). В вашем случае key={item} не является хорошим вариантом

Comment: А в чем смысл сначала фильтровать а потом рендерить через map()? Почему бы не за одно действие?

Comment: С точки зрения читаемости

Comment: А производительность?

Comment: +- эквивалентна

Comment: Серьёзно?) _O(n)_ и _O(2n)_ алгоритмы эквивалентны? Запустите тест на массиве из 10000 элементов, и поймете что вы ой как заблуждаетесь

Comment: Где вы видели обозначение вычислительной сложности с константой перед n? Ваш вариант, как и мой, имеет вычислительную сложность O(n). А я, как уже сказал, сделал это для удобной читаемости ответа. Вы можете отдельным ответом написать свой, оптимальный вариант

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
  const { data: { items, title }} = this.props;
  return(
    <div>         
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, i) => item === "iPhone 7" && <Item key={`item-${i}`} name={item} />)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```